# Significance of PermGen Space

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, permgen

What is the significance of PermGen space in java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does PermGen actually stand for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318942/what-does-permgen-actually-stand-for)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

PermGen space is reserved for long-term objects - mostly `Class` objects loaded by the `ClassLoader`.  PermGen will not be garbage collected except under very special circumstances (specifically, when the `ClassLoader` that loaded those classes goes out of scope).

This is a garbage collection optimization - if objects that we don't expect to be garbage collected are stored separately, it compacts the space where the rest of the objects are stored, which leads to less work for the garbage collector.

Comment: The ClassLoader you are referring to is the System class loader?

Where are the classes loaded by the bootstrap class loader stored?

Comment: The classes loaded by the bootstrap loader are the ones that are integral to the language, like `String` and `Object`.  This is part of the native implementation of the JVM, so there's no standard answer regarding "where".

Comment: Fine. So will the permgen contain the classes loaded by system class loader?

Comment: Yes, thats correct.  Keep in mind that we are talking about the Sun implementation of the JVM.  PermGen is not a part of the specification, and so another JVM (such as JRockit, mentioned by another poster) will not have it.

Answer (score 8):

The PermGen is specific to VMs having generational garbage collection.

If you use, say, JRockit, the "significance of PermGen" is non-existent because JRockit doesn't have that concept.

It uses to be common, a few years ago, when the weird "out of PermGen space" errors started appearing and that nobody knew yet whose fault it was (Tomcat + Hibernate + Sun VM used to trigger this) to replace one of the component (nowadays the problems are understood, but years ago when they started cropping it was hardly possible to find any information on this).  You could replace Tomcat with Resin or the Sun VM with JRockIt etc.

I think it's important to point out that PermGen are not part of the Java specs and only an implementation detail of (quite) some VMs.

Answer (score 6):

The only thing you really need to know is that PermGen space is separate from the general heap and not affected by the `-Xmx` VM parameter. If you have an application that loads lots of class definitions (like an application server or an IDE) then you can set the PermGen space size using the `-XX:MaxPermSize` VM option.

Answer (score 4):

The permanent generation holds meta-data describing user classes (classes that are not part of the Java language).

Applications with large code-base can fill up this segment of the heap which will cause `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen`.  This is not affected by the -Xmx setting or how much memory you have on the machine.  To set a new initial size, use `-XX:PermSize=64m`.  To set a maximum size, use `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m`

Comment: What do you mean by "classes that are not part of the Java language"?  Do you know of any classes that would not be stored in PermGen?