# Does .NET have something like Java's permgen?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, permgen

So I've got a pretty standard spring, hibernate, tomcat environment.. yet I'm getting permgens locally and on CI.

I know there is a TEMPORARY fix (i.e. increasing the memory assigned to permgen) but this still is only temporary. I'd rather not imagine what a production environment looks like given what I'm seeing.

(a bit of a comparison question)
In .NET I have not seen anything similar. Does .NET have its version of permgen?

(in case you do not know what permgen is [Significance of PermGen Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238522/significance-of-permgen-space) )

Comment: You are running spring, hibernate and Tomcat...with C#? I am confused.

Comment: It would not be a c# thing it would be a clr thing. c# is just a language

Comment: You could describe a bit more what the permgen is, and its properties. And not sure how your second paragraph relates to the rest. And what are you interested in?

Comment: If you don't know what permgen is  see this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238522/significance-of-permgen-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the CLR (C# is "just" a CLR language) does not have a permanent generation, see [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx#generations).

Btw, future versions of the JVM - currently expected at the latest for Java 8 - won't have permgen either (see [Oracle discusses Java 7 & 8 new features on video](http://dhruba.name/2011/07/06/oracle-discusses-java-7-8-new-features-on-video/)) (basically as a result of "merging" the "classic" Sun HotSpot VM that has permgen and JRockit JVM).

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing in the CLR. Just a ordinary heap. The garbage collector (GC) is generational, with three generations. One for young objects, one for long living and one for very long living objects. There is also a lage object heap (LOH). The GC treats the LOH a bit differently in order to increase efficiency. See [Large Object Heap Uncovered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx)

Comment: What about for interned strings? Are those not effectively "permgen"?

Comment: Interning is done for string literals (i.e. strings visible as plain text in the source code), but not for strings created dynamically at runtime. You cannot use it as a general memory management system.