# PermGen space Memory leak

Tags: java, postgresql, struts2, tomcat6, netbeans-7

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

I am getting this error when deploying the application and server is hanging after 15 to 20 min.

Comment: When deploying or when _re_deploying / reloading the context? Have you tried increasing the PermGen Space?

Comment: Netbeans is notorious for memory leaks on redeployment

Comment: Redeploying multiple times increases the PERmanent GENeration allocated size. You just need to restart the Application Server after a certain number of deploys. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318942/what-does-permgen-actually-stand-for

Answer (score 0):

There could be a very specific reason why PermGen error is being produced.
But..

Allocate more space to the tomcat JVM with ( in the JAVA_OPTS)

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

or whatever size you want.

Do take a look at http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space/

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to increase `PermGen` heap size in `catalina.bat` of tomcat server; this can give you some breathing space but eventually this will also return in `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen` space after some time.

```
Follow these steps to increase the PermGen Heap size:

1) Go to Tomcat installation directory i.e C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.14\bin in Windows.

2) Add JAVA_OPTS in your catalina.bat

set JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx10246m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=356m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=356m"
```

Increasing PermGen space can prevent `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen` in tomcat only for some time and it will eventually occur based on how many times you redeploy your web application, its best to find the offending class which is causing memory leak in tomcat and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a memory leak, it signals that you have a Permanent Generation leak in your application, what means that whenever you redeploy an application in your application server it leaves a whole lot of classes behind. These old class definitions end up in your JVM permanent generation, eating up precious memory therefore the solution is never to increase *Permgen* size, this "solution" is a time bomb.

As is also the case with other types of memory leaks, **there is no golden tool** or **a fixed how-to list** that you can follow to magically solve the problem. There are many possible cases and many ways to solve it.

Having said that I recommend to use ***Plumbr*** ([official website](https://plumbr.eu/)) and here you have a very **usefulguide to solve it**:

[Solving run-time OutOfMemoryError](https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/permgen-space#solution)

Good luck.