# PermGen space increasing due to LogManager.getLogger(Logger.class.getName());

Tags: java, memory, log4j2, visualvm

I have been experiencing a PermGen memory issue and using Java VisualVM to debug it.

I traced the problem to a single line of code which is causing memory use to increase and never decrease. With this line of code no classes are getting unloaded.

The line of code is :

```
LogManager.getLogger(Logger.class.getName());
```

I am using log4j2. Does anyone have any suggestions to a fix to this line to be able to get rid of the memory problem?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/320469/4296831

Comment: Can you add more detail? Is this a webapp, j2ee, or standalone? What log4j2 functions are you using? (All loggers async, mixed sync/async,...) if webapp, where are the log4j2 jars & config file? (In container lib or in webinf/lib?)

Answer (score 0):

This is an educated guess. As suggested by [the link offered @Joachim in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318942/what-does-permgen-actually-stand-for/320469#320469), increasing `PermGen` space implies either an increasing number of classes loaded by the ClassLoader, or an increasing number of interned Strings.

([See this StackOverflow question to learn more about String interning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-string-interning))

Based on this, I would change your code to reference something static, which perhaps `getName()` does not give you.

I recommend either:

```
LogManager.getLogger(Logger.class.getName().intern());
```

Or as is more usually seen:

```
LogManager.getLogger(Logger.class);
```

---

But are you actually meaning to log against `Logger.class`?

Perhaps consider actually doing:

```
LogManager.getLogger(MyClassWhereLoggingHappens.class);
```